# Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message could not open for reading

Tags: php, csv, converters, phpexcel

I am creating a form for users that will allow them to upload `.csv` files and `xls/xlsx` files. Currently, the program does allow them to upload `.csv` files, which are used to update the `Oracle 11g` database I am working off of. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to open, then right the `xsl/xlsx` files to `csv`'s. I keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open uploaded.xls for reading! File does not exist, or it is not readable.' in /opt/apache/servers/planninganddesign/htdocs/LG/SLCCA/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLERead.php:80 Stack trace: #0 /opt/apache/servers/planninganddesign/htdocs/LG/SLCCA/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php(1164): PHPExcel_Shared_OLERead->read('uploaded.xls') #1 <DIRECTORY> (612): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5->_loadOLE('uploaded.xls') #2 /opt/apache/servers/planninganddesign/htdocs/LG/SLCCA/update_handler2.php(12): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5->load('uploaded.xls') #3 {main} thrown in /opt/apache/servers/planninganddesign/htdocs/LG/SLCCA/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLERead.php on line 80
```

It's a very long error, but I think just the first line is my main issue at the moment.

**update2.php** (form) [I doubt you need this]:

```
<?php require('reader.php'); ?>

<form name="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="update_handler2.php" method="post" >

   <u>GF:</u> <input type="file" name="uploaded"><br>
   <u>GF:</u> <input type="number" name="numbers"><br>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

**update_handler2.php** (handler):

```
<?php require_once'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'; ?>

<?php

    $file = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];

    $inputFileType = 'Excel5';
    $inputFileName = '$file';

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

    $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

    foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
        $objWriter->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
        $objWriter->save($loadedSheetName.'.csv');
    }

?>
```

Does anyone know how to fix to this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$inputFileName = '$file';
```

Is your file really called `$file` (you're quoting it as a string literal).... or is the filename in the variable `$file`

```
$inputFileName = $file;
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know putting it in '' makes it a literal. Obvi I'm only a week into programming xD lol! Thanks a lot, this seems to have fixed my error. I will accept answer in 10mins once I can! I appreciate you helping the noob out.

Comment: If you use double quotes (`"`), then PHP will interpolate variable values when it encounters variable names, if you use single quotes (`'`), then it will be a straight string literal [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: You learn something new every day :) I'd up but I need 15 rep for that lol. Thanks a lot!